# How to solve curl ssl v3 alert handshake failure?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, command-line, openssl

I'm trying to use curl on a website on my wamp server locally.

However it fails with the error:

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Here is my code:

```
$url = sprintf( 'http://thepiratebay.se/search/%s/0/99/%d/', urlencode($keyword ), $category);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cert/cacert.pem");
```

I tried adding the below lines as suggested on a [site](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=534):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');
```

But it gives a new error:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

My php version:

```
5.4.16
```

My curl version:

```
7.30.0
```

My openssl version:

```
OpenSSL/0.9.8y
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [report by SSLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=thepiratebay.se&s=141.101.118.195&latest) this site only supports TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA* cipher suites.

> ```
> OpenSSL/0.9.8y
> ```

OpenSSL 0.9.8 does not support any ECDHE ciphers and thus there are no common ciphers between client and server. This causes the SSL handshake to fail. There is no workaround but you need to upgrade your OpenSSL. Note that this probably includes recompiling curl/PHP too so that they make use of the newer version of OpenSSL. Or you might get a newer version of WAMP which will probably include the newer version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. I had a unix box with OpenSSL version 1.0.1e-fips installed. My same code worked like a charm. Cheers.